# A problem with uniform distribution?

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, random-variables, expected-value, uniform-distribution

> In a game Alis and Daniel shoot arrows on a circular target with a
> radius of R.
>
> Alis throws arrows such that their distance from the center have
> Continuous uniform distribution (0,R) - o,R are the parameters for
> uniform distribution.
>
> While Daniel throws arrows such that their distance from the center have
> random Continuous uniform distribution (From the
> target)

I was asked to calculate the expected value for the distance of the arrows for both participant.

For Alis it's R/2 but what about Daniel? I didn't understand what's given about him, what are the parameters for him...

---

I claimed: "For Alis it's R/2" Proof:

The expected value for random variable with uniform distribution (a,b) (with parameters a and b) is (a+b)/2

Comment: What does "Daniel's arrows Have random uniform distribution (From the target)" mean?

Comment: @angryavian updated the question

Comment: Your update doesn’t help, and I suspect that it’s wrong: I suspect that Daniel’s arrows are supposed to have uniform random distribution over the target.

Comment: @BrianM.Scott ok and if we suppose this, what will be the parameters? (It could be problem with translation)

Comment: @MrCalc The "uniform distribution over the circular target" is not the usual one-dimensional uniform distributions whose parameters are the endpoints of the interval. It is defined such that the probability of a subregion of the target is proportional to the area of the subregion. It doesn't have parameters in the same way the one-dimensional uniform distribution over an interval does.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

HINT: Presumably it means that the probability that Daniel’s arrow lands in a given region of the target is proportional to the area of the region. The area of an annulus of mean radius $r$ and width $dr$ is $dA=2\pi r\,dr$, and the area of the target is $\pi R^2$, so the probability that it lands in that annulus is

$$\frac{dA}{\pi R^2}=\frac{2\pi r\,dr}{\pi R^2}=\frac2{R^2}r\,dr\,.$$

Alternatively, the cumulative distribution function $F(r)$ for $0\le r\le R$ is given by

$$F(r)=\frac{\pi r^2}{\pi R^2}=\frac{r^2}{R^2}\,.$$

Use whichever approach you like to get the probability density function, and then use that to calculated the expected value from the definition of expected value.

Comment: But what are the parameters for Daniel? For alis they are 0 and R

Comment: @MrCalc: I suspect that you’re intended to work it from scratch using the definition of expected value, as I did and as **Arash** has now done. The parameter is plainly $R$, but I’ve no idea what the relevant distribution is called. It is derived from the uniform distribution over the disk, but is not uniform, since larger distances from the centre are clearly more probable than smaller ones.

Comment: you can't calculate expected value using F(r) or probability, there is no law for this

Comment: @MrCalc: Of course you can. You just use the definition.

Comment: I have one law to calculate expected value using integral of f

Comment: @MrCalc: If, as I suspect, by $f$ you mean the probability density function, you can obtain it directly from my first approach or by differentiating the cum. dist. function of my second approach. That is in fact the point of my answer.

Comment: " so the probability that it lands in that annulus" that should be 1 as it will hit the circle for sure....

Comment: @MrCalc: No. You need to read what is actually written: the annulus in question is not the entire disk. And the use of $dA$ for its area and $dr$ for its width ought to be a big clue that you should be thinking of a very narrow annulus that you might use in setting up the integral for the expected value.

Comment: @MrCalc: No. The inner radius of my annulus is $r-\frac12dr$, the outer radius is $r+\frac12dr$, and the area is $2\pi r\,dr$. Everything that I did there is rather basic integral calculus.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the question is:

1. A's arrows hit the target so that the distribution of the distance from the center is uniform, i.e.,
   $f_A(r,\theta )= \begin{cases}
    \frac{1}{2\pi R} & 0<r<R, 0<\theta<2\pi \\
    0, &\text{otherwise}
   \end{cases}
   $,
2. D's arrows hit the target uniformly distributed over the target, i.e.,
   $f_D(r,\theta )= \begin{cases}
    \frac{r}{\pi R^2} & 0<r<R, 0<\theta<2\pi \\
    0, &\text{otherwise}
   \end{cases}
   $.

Further, if the question asks for the expected distance of the arrow from the center for each of them, then:

$E_A\{r\} = \int\limits_{r=0}^{R} r\frac{1}{R}dr = \frac{1}{2}R$, and

$E_D\{r\} = \int\limits_{r=0}^{R} r\frac{2r}{R^2}dr=\frac{2}{3}R$.

Comment: yeah, can you kindly explain the calculations for (,)

Comment: and (,)

Comment: Brian M. Scott's answer, <https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3968551/866952> is more thorough. I didn't see it while I was typing. I just assumed that the angle is uniformly distributed on $[0,2\pi]$. If the question asks for the expectation of the distance between the two hit points of A and D, then the angle must also be taken into account. If not, it doesn't change the result.

Comment: you have a mistake calculating {}, th formula says to take r multiplied by (,) but u took something else, plus where pi went?

Comment: I think it is correct. Calculate the marginal dist. for r:
$f_D(r)=\int\limits_{\theta=0}^{2\pi} \frac{r}{\pi R^2} d\theta = 2\pi \frac{r}{\pi R^2} = \frac{2r}{R^2}$.

Comment: But... you wrote something else above... you wrote that (,)=12